# disabling DST time change or disabling zoneinfo file updates in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, timezone

I am having Ubuntu 18 web server with MySQL database. We do calculation based on timezone.

i read that changing the sever timezone to GMT+_7 we can solve the DST time changes, as i tried it already and i was not getting my old data.

so my questions are below

How to disable DST time changes alone in Ubuntu 18, i couldn't find any options and searching also did not give me any results
How to stop updating the zonefile automatically in Ubuntu 18, if i can update the rules for the zone file.

Comment: If you do not need local time, why are you not just using UTC?

Comment: the system was deployed some time back with MDT timezone, but later realized this issue, so already there are lot of data in the mysql db which i cannot change or  lose. i have to fix or avoid the issue in future..